# TableLayout row and column in android with java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I designed a dynamic table in android with java. The table has 3 columns but the last column displays data out/off the screen which is not visible in the screen but are there.

---

**How can I make the data of the third column to continue display below it and make all data be visible to users??**

---

This is the java codes iv used to achieve that:

```
LinearLayout main_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    TableLayout table_service = new TableLayout(this);
    table_service.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    for(ServiceArray s : arr_service){

        TableRow tr_item = new TableRow(this);
        tr_item.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ));

        TextView date = new TextView(this);
        date.setText(s.getDateOfService());
        date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        date.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ));
        date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        TextView mileage = new TextView(this);
        mileage.setText(s.getMileage());
        mileage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mileage.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ));
        mileage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        TextView description = new TextView(this);
        description.setText(s.getDescription());
        description.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        description.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ));
        description.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        tr_item.addView(date);
        tr_item.addView(mileage);
        tr_item.addView(description);

        table_service.addView(tr_item);
    }


    main_layout.addView(table_service);
    setContentView(main_layout);
```

---

xml is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Image [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ut3axf9sjgfcge/2014-03-28-17-13-39%20%282%29.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your xml layout?

Comment: Iv updated the code Daniel..
Infact i need to span the row and fit the 3rd data into the cell itself and avoid data to be hidden off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `setColumnShrinkable()` at the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnShrinkable%28int,%20boolean%29). This will shrink your column to make it fit on screen.

Also, take a look at `setColumnStrechable()` at the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnStretchable%28int,%20boolean%29) to make the column strech if the device is in landscape mode (as the column might not be wide enough). Let me know how it works.